# What’s the reason for the zero article after a preposition and countable noun in “a change of X” and in “a switch from X to Y”?

Tags: prepositions, articles, countable-nouns, noun-phrases, zero-article

I am a non-native speaker of English and therefore need your help. The question is: why do we use the zero article in the phrases “a change of X” and “a switch from X to Y”?

For instance:

- a change **of** address
- a change **of** government
- a switch **from** student **to** teacher

The words following the prepositions set in bold (that is, *address, teacher, student,* and *government*) are all countable nouns, are not they?

So why do they get to be used without an article given that they are countable nouns?

How are they different from *a change* and *a switch*, which do have an article before them?

Comment: I haven’t yet found an existing question on our site that answers this, but I believe that the answer is because the countable nouns following those prepositions are here being used in a generic way. However, this case does ***not*** appear to be covered in [the Wikipedia article mentioning zero-article marking in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English#Zero_article), which mentions only cases like *going to work/school/prison*.

Comment: Related and possible duplicates although not always with good answers yet: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/104910 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/104579 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/37738 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/202106 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/277627 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/313276 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/306016 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95496 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/104023 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/108077 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/175604 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/274220 and so and so forth.

Comment: I find the answer given below is quite convincing. I like it very much. My grammar book says "The article _a/an is_ usually dropped after _sort of, kind of_ and _type of_, but structures with articles are possible in an informal style." (M.Swan, _Practical English Usage_, §551) We see similar phenomena in those expression like _go to office/school, I am home/downstairs, go downtown_, or _we elected him mayor_, or _assume office_. I see they are occasions where nouns are conceptualized. Also there's examples like _side by side, in hand, in question, at night, by bus_, and etc.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the article, noun and proposition “**a change of**” does not restrict your grammar choices for **government**.

An indefinite mass or plural noun does not require an article. If you are using the noun **government** as an indefinite mass noun (i.e. referring to the essential nature of government or the condition of having government [what you mean by “generic way]) then you choose not to use an article – also called choosing the zero (null) article or zero-marking. Avoiding further specificity by not adding an article forces you to consider the essential nature of the thing the noun names.

The following are all grammatically correct:

- a change in government
- a change in governments
- a change in a government
- a change in the government
- a change in the governments

And so are:

- change in government
- change in governments
- change in a government
- change in the government
- change in the governments
- the change in government
- the change in governments
- the change in a government
- the change in the government
- the change in the governments
- the changes in government
- the changes in governments
- the changes in a government
- the changes in the government
- the changes in the governments

These are all grammatically correct and have different meanings.

- What I want to see all around the world is **changes in the governments** that are most strict. I want them to become less strict.
- **The changes in the governments** of Northern Europe in the latter half of the twentieth century were a response to the horrors of World War II.
- You are unlikely to see **a change in a government** unless the people of that nation are empowered to protest.

I also made a switch from **of** to **in** because **in** works better with all these other variations. But let’s consider that difference as well.

- What we need is a change **in** government.
- What we need is a change **of** government.

These two sentences use **government** as an indefinite mass noun, which means we are mainly concerned with the governance of the country. The sentence with **in** implies that an internal change of the current government is acceptable, such as a change in foreign policy. The sentence with **of** implies that the current government needs to be replaced by a new government (through election, coup or revolution) to achieve **the change of government** we ultimately want.

Comment: Master posits a vast difference between two situations where no article is used: the zero article, less specifying than the indefinite article, and at the other extreme, the null article, an emphasising/venerating alternative for the definite article. Follow Lawrence's link at [Using 'empire' without article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414555/using-empire-without-article).